# How to apply procedural material on a mesh?

Tags: texturing, materials, procedural

I tried to use a texture coordinate, but it didn't help. UVs don't work. Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: Hello, you say that UV doesn't work but it should, maybe you need to unwrap and adjust the UVs in the UV Editor?

Comment: I adjust it in the edit mode by selecting all -> pressing U -> smart uv project. Is that correct way?

Comment: did you put a Texture Coordinate (UV output socket) > Mapping > Brick Texture (Vector socket)? Smart UV Project should work for your object.

Comment: Yes, I used this order of nodes: Texture coordinate "generated" to  Mapping "vector" to Brick Texture "vector"

Comment: please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: [file](https://pasteall.org/blend/3f476c358869498db5dfe47133ff8178) - Here it is

Comment: Bro, the uv map is messed up. UV wrap it properly and trey to match it properly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Maulik says, your UV is messed up, so the texture won't be correctly projected if you use the UV output socket:

[image]

So re-unwrap your cylinder, you can switch to front view and choose *Unwrap > Cylinder Projection* for example. You'll need to unwrap the top face and make it match as much as possible I guess:

[image]

Use the *Texture Coordinate* "UV" output socket:

[image]

Comment: it still didn't help( When I press any button that changes the UV map, nothing happens

Comment: in the 3D view, select your cylinder, switch to Edit mode, choose front view, press U to unwrap > Cylinder Projection

Comment: That's what I do! Exactly these steps. And when I get proper UV map, I try to modify it in the UV map editor, and nothing happens. I even try to move the whole map [link 1](https://ibb.co/FqPGNFw) [link 2](https://ibb.co/b5DnJy7)

Comment: what do you mean by "nothing happens"? You show an image in your screenshot but in the file you share it was a Brick Texture node

Comment: Sorry for the image, but when I modify UV it doesn't matter what image is shown in the UV Editing, right? If yes, I select everything in the Edit mode and UV Editing and try to move it in the UV Editing

Comment: sure but if you've changed some settings I'm unable to see it, please share your last file so that I can test it

Comment: I haven't made any changes, but here's the video of my actions - [video](https://cdn.api.video/vod/vi6EGZ5Z3RgUwwfgzWVkBDS/mp4/1080/source.mp4)

Comment: yes but what about the shader editor? are you using the Texture Coordinate UV output?

Comment: [Yes](https://ibb.co/xLPMjzh)

Comment: You need to use the Texture Coordinate "UV" output, see my edit

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122398/discussion-between-hacker-man-and-moonboots).